# relational database and composite keys

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many, normalization, database-normalization

I have three tables normalised to this:

```
  +---------------+                                                 
  |Product        |                                                 
  +---------------+                                                 
  |productCode(PK)|                                                 
  |title          |                                                 
  |description    |                                                 
  |price          |                                                 
  |productGroup   |                                                 
  +---------------+                                                 

          m                                                         
          |                                                         
          |                                                         
          1                                                         

 +------------------+                                               
 |Purchase Info     |                                               
 +------------------+                                               
 |productCode(FK)   |                                               
 |purchaseNumber(FK)|                                               
 |offerPrice        |                                               
 |quantity          |                                               
 +------------------+                                               

          1                                                         
          |                                                         
          |                                                         
          m                                                         

+---------------------+                                             
|Purchase             |           +-----------------+               
+---------------------+           |Branch           |               
|purchaseNumber(PK)   |           +-----------------+               
|productCode(FK)      |           |branchNumber(PK) |      more          
|branchNumber(FK)     |  m-----0  |buildingName     |  x2  (salesPerson,          
|salesPersonNumber(FK)|           |city             |      accountNo)         
|accountNumber(FK)    |           |postcode         |      similar tables         
|time                 |           |telNumber        |               
|tillNo               |           +-----------------+               
+---------------------+                                             
1 = one
0 = many
```

But I am not quite sure how these now function as a 'database'. Before this was normalised the `purchaseInfo` table did not exist and the attributes belonged in the `purchase` table. **But** `product` and `purchase` were a many to many relationship.

What I am wanting is for a user to be able to add a new purchase with the fields of:

- product - `productCode`
- quantity - `quantity`
- offer price - `offerPrice`

And be able to have the ability to get the content from every other table:

How would I set up the MySQL query?

I thought of something like this:

```
INSERT into `purchaseInfo` (productCode, purchaseNumber, offerPrice, quantity)
VALUES ('".$productCode."', '".$purchaseNumber."', '".$offerPrice."', '".$quantity."');
```

But that doesn't really make sense to me.

Any other ideas or explanations on what I am actually doing? Sorry I have been taught this subject very badly and am not quite sure what is going on!

Comment: Why do you have productCode in your Purchase table? Your purchase <-> product relation should be contained totally within your Purchase Info table

Answer (score 0):

Each record in Purchase is like a check that you get in the supermarket (e.g. 10 bottles of Heineken and 2 loaves of bread)

Each record in Purchase Info is one line on that check (e.g. 10 bottles of Heineken)

Each record in Product is one type of product (e.g. "Heineken")

So, when you make a purchase you will probably need at least two inserts
1) INSERT into PURCHASE
2) INSERT into PURCHASE_INFO - as many times as you have different products in one purchase

On another subject: you should not concatenate strings when inserting. Use parametrized queries (with ? marks) instead.